# 50 Hz and 60 Hz combined neutrals

Tags: inverter, neutral

I have two inverters. Inverter A is producing 220 V, 50 Hz while inverter B is producing 110 V, 60 Hz. Can they share a neutral on the output?

Comment: Depends on many things not available for answering that.

Comment: I don't think the frequency or voltage makes a difference, but the current does. I would choose the wire gauge as if the current was going to add up.

Comment: Is that isolated or grounded neutral?

Comment: Too little detail, really. What types of inverters?

Comment: Wow.  Two different voltages and frequencies and you want to share a neutral.  Sounds dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not!

This will overload the neutral wire in question.

Sharing neutral only works with multi-phase supplies *which are in sync*.  Classically the American 120/240V split-phase or a 3- phase "wye" distribution.  *All two or three phases are in sync*, therefore neutral sees only differential current.

The simplest way of modeling this is in DC with two battery stacks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6xpiW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Think about it. What is the maximum worst-case current on the center wire (neutral)?  Try every combination.

See? :) It's like magic. Neutral current is the differential of the two "hot" currents, and its worst case is one leg at 20A and the other at 0A.  *Neutral passively cannot exceed either hot wire current, **and that's why it doesn't need a fuse/breaker***.

This metaphor continues with split-phase power - both batteries are "flipping over" 50/60 times a second (well really 100/120), **but they are flipping together** so it works.

It also works with 3-phase power - the math gets wonky, but the worst case is 2 phases at 100% load with the third phase at 0% load - in that case neutral sees 100% but no more.  It still works.

But what happens *if only one battery* is flipping repeatedly?  Now we have a problem.  When you have this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fojqZ7.png)</sup>

Yeah, neutral can see 40A and you have an overload problem.

When your sources are AC and out of sync, this is the scenario you will have *some of the time*.

"But isn't 200% overload 50% of the time the same as 100% load 100% of the time?"   No, because of the way Ohm's Law interacts with Watt's Law.  A wire overloaded to 200% makes *four times* the heat it's rated for, not two times.  Thus 200% load x 50% duty cycle = 200% heat. Still suffering the effects of overloading.

Separately from this, you are likely to see bizarre effects because of the unrelated systems interacting.  It seems a foolish way to save a wire.

If you're keen on saving money on wire, then aluminum at larger sizes is the win. We know how to use it properly now; use terminals rated for aluminum wire and torque them to specification.  I bet you have some fat wire runs to a battery, solar panel or whatever.  I have seen several home power projects *fail* because they locked into copper, bought what they could afford, and it wasn't near enough. Sadly for the same coin they could've bought enormous aluminum feeder and their project would have worked.

If you are doing 120V you are probably doing the North American "bonded TT" type earthing/grounding, where we have a *neutral-ground equipotential bond* at the first disconnect past the source, and keep neutral and ground separate thereafter. This is important.  I know it's annoying to run 3 wires that are bonded together at the main panel, but it's important for safety - the other thing has been tried.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanation, I assumed that the phases would create a problem but lack the technical knowledge to confirm this. Unfortunately, I have little choice but to install an alternative power system in a foreign country where I cannot find technical support so I am asking a lot of dumb questions. :) unfortunately I don’t have enough reputation yet to vote your question up.